# How to Print to Console (Terminal) inside a system call

Tags: linux, printing, console, terminal, kernel

how can i print something (for debugging purpose) to console inside a linux system call?

Or is there any not very diffucult way of debugging kernel code?

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The accepted way of printing inside the kernel is via `printk()`.

Comment: thanks for the answer i am trying it, do you know any active forum related to kernel development? any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

You should also check the different modifiers to printk (such as KERNEL_DEBUG) which will control where/how the messages are printed, including whether they are printed to all active terminals or just the system buffer